# Using autotools to generate application specific *.conf files

Tags: autotools

I'm new to using autotools so forgive me if this sounds a little bit basic but googling didn't show up much.

How would I go about generating a custom conf file with autotools.

Seeing as configure based on m4 contains the necessary macros and generates the required files.

Some hunting and reading seems to suggest I could do something like
add:

> AC_CONFIG_FILES([appname.conf])

To my configure.am.

Then create an appname.conf.in file.

What I'm not clear on is how I populate custom macros i.e.

```
LOG_DIR=@log_dir@
CACHE_DIR=@cache_dir@
```

to

So when configure gets run it produces

```
LOG_DIR=/var/log
CACHE_DIR=/mycachedir
```

etc...

Answer (score 3):

The information you seem to be missing is [`AC_SUBST`](https://www.gnu.org/s/hello/manual/autoconf/Setting-Output-Variables.html), which sets up the substitutions.

E.g. in configure.ac:

```
TEST_SUB="hello world"
AC_SUBST(TEST_SUB)

AC_CONFIG_FILES(test.conf)
```

In test.conf.in:

```
TEST_VAR=@TEST_SUB@
```

Gives test.conf:

```
TEST_VAR=hello world
```

(If you're curious have a look in the Makefile.in files that automake generates to see how it uses this mechanism. The `AM_CONDITIONAL`s get turned into two things, one for each case, one of which gets made into a comment by a substitution)